# Sharepoint Designer changes browser enabled form?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I currently had a browser enabled InfoPath form which would open from SharePoint.  I recently made changes in SharePoint Designer (specifics here, it's the accepted answer: [Simple way to color code a column in a document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20088/simple-way-to-color-code-a-column-in-a-document-library)) and now my InfoPath form will still open in a browser and can be saved, but if I want to modify it, it wont let me open the form in a browser. It has to be opened in the client application. Any help/suggestions as to how I can modify it through the browser?

Comment: are you receiving any error or something when you open to modify in browser?

Comment: What are you even talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just want to use rules within InfoPath to handle that?  You can create display rules based on the value of fields.

Comment: I have it set to open in a browser, but for some reason when I click it on the Sharepoint server (only to modify not create) it opens it in the infopath client.

Answer (score 0):

just check what is the extension of the form- .xsn or .xml?

fyi .xml will open in browser and .xsn will open in client